# Compile CPP files into lib.so

Tags: c++, flutter, cmake, shared-libraries

I am using a library which is ics open vpn it is for Android it contains some CPP files but I am a flutter developer CPP files are not supported directly on flutter that's why there are many projects on GitHub in which they have compiled the CPP files into lib.so files it is working perfectly with flutter how to do that ?(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKYBi.png)

[CPP files](https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn/tree/master/main/src/main/cpp)

Here is a project in which a developer did that [lib.so files](https://github.com/nizwar/nizvpn/tree/master/android/vpnLib/src/main/jniLibs)

Comment: you need to pick a compiler. then decide what platforms / architectures you want to support and where you are going to do the builds and whether you want to do cross-compiling, and then decide whether and how you want to automate it all. this is a very broad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But cpp or c++ when compiling becomes lib.so file The project on github is ready and prepared to be compiled, export it to android studio and compile the project, in the end a lib.so file will appear.

Comment: Really is that that much easy thanks 